# Where does Cinnamon store its Desktop Art settings?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, cinnamon

Running Linux Mint 16 right now, Cinnamon 64-bit. I'm trying to find out where Cinnamon stores my desktop settings. Precisely looking for where the desktop image settings are stored and want to figure out how to manipulate it via the command line for a bash script I've written.

tl;dr: can I change cinnamon's desktop image from the command line?

Any clues or tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cinnamon) gave me the correct clues, but the actual way to do it is to do the following:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file://<path to file>"
```

Answer (score 5):

Citation from [the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cinnamon):

> #### Default desktop background wallpaper path
>
> When you add a wallpaper from a custom path. in Cinnamon Settings, Cinnamon copies it to `~/.cinnamon/background`. Thus, with every change of your wallpaper you would have to add your updated wallpaper again from the settings menu or copy / symlink it manually to `~/.cinnamon/background`.

Answer (score 1):

Gsettings also delivers the path to the current background-image.

```
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri
```