# Where do I find the path of the current desktop background in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-environment, wallpaper

I'm using Cinnamon on Devuan Chimaera. I'm trying to migrate an earlier user home directory (from Devuan Beowulf). Specifically, I'm trying to use the same background image. But I can't figure out where the chosen background image, or the link/path to it, is stored! I couldn't find anything relevant under `~/.cinnamon`. Where is it? :-(

<sub>Note: Related question which doesn't seem to answer my question: [Where does Cinnamon store its Desktop Art settings?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115424/where-does-cinnamon-store-its-desktop-art-settings)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri
```

Worked for me.